# How to remove an account from the Visual Studio 2019 source control authentication window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I inherited my work machine from a colleague but I can't seem to remove his account from the Visual Studio source control authentication. Every time I try to do something that requires authentication with the remote repository (e.g. push/pull) I see this prompt. I've also already removed his credentials from the Windows Credential Manager.

[image: Screenshot of the sign-in window]

Answer (score 3):

You can remove your account from File > Account Settings > Remove

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That worked for me in VS2022 too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Credential Manager (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager) and remove all his credentials from "Web Credentials" and "Windows Credentials".